# XML Serialization using XMLSerializer produced incomplete xml

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, file-io, stream

Consider the following code to serialize any object of type T to an xml ,

```
public void Serialize<T>(T instance , string fileName)
{
    //stream is filestream since to handle hard shutdown of the sytem corrupting the xml    because of windows cache behavior by using WriteThrough option
    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write,  FileShare.None,1024, FileOptions.WriteThrough))
    {
        XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
        writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        writer.Indentation = 2;
        writer.IndentChar = ' ';

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        serializer.Serialize(writer, instance);
    }
}
```

This code produces an output which looks like this ,

```
<Root>
   <Parent>
       <Element1></Element1>
       <Element2></Element2>
       <Element3></Element3>
   </Parent>
   <Parent
```

**The problem with this xml is , this is half written.**

Why does this happen and how to re-solve this problem ?

PS:

1.Not always this is reproducible. Only once i had seen it.

2.Immediately after the serialization , system gets restarted (anything to do with cache , stream not flushed ??)

3.When i counted the characters in the xml file , the number is 1021 . Does it have something to do with the buffer size which is used while creating the file stream ?

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**

I could find a way to reproduce this problem.

Run a loop which calls this serialize method (say 100 times) by passing an object which (when serialized) has atleast 100kb of data. Inbetween just close the program (command window if its console app) the last file which was getting written will have half written data as i mentioned above.

Any way to overcome this problem (i.e file not getting affected though program gets closed or restart/shutdown occurs) ? This occurs even if i increase the buffer size to 4096 and close the xmltextwriter by wrapping it in an using statement.

Answer (score 2):

You have to close/flush the `XmlTextWriter`. Put that in a using block for example.

Comment: I could sense that , but the worst part is this never happened in last 5 years after this code was written originally. A change was done recently to change the Stream to FileStream , so my eyes were fully on whether the changed piece of code would have introduced the issue . Any explanations/articles which explains not closing the xmltextwriter would have been the real cause of this issue ?

Comment: If an object is IDisposable, you always have to dispose of it correctly, and really there is nothing more to it. If it has worked for years, that's only a random coincidence. Not flushing a streaming object leads exactly to losing the last parts of the buffers. Even the reference won't say much else than that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter.flush%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I don't understand... Let's say your XmlWriter is writing data and you close the program, what should happen? The process is killed, so your XmlWriter has no chance to finish writing, so you will have a half-written file. Maybe you could write to a temporary file, and then rename it when it's completely written.

Comment: I am just trying to see whether .net offers any other API to overcome this situation (i.e complete the write part while program is closing) .

Comment: That's a whole different question from where we started. Anyway I doubt you could do anything if the process is being killed. You can only prepare by always having a consistent, recoverable state on the filesystem. Eg. by writing to a temp file and renaming it to its final name when everything has been written. Or by doing transactions like a database system does.